# Crash when sending data without connection via Socket in Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, crash

I'm using C language to send data via socket in Linux by using command

```
send(ServerSocket, cSendBuff, strlen(cSendBuff), 0);
```

The procedure is:

> 1. Create socket
> 2. Connect to Server
> 3. while (condition): Send data

When I run this program in Linux environment, if it is connected, there is no problem. But in order to take care of failed connection when running, I check some cases and got results as below:

**Case 1:**

> 1. Create socket: No creation (comment out creating function)
> 2. Connection to Server: No connection (comment out connecting function)
> 3. Send data --> **Failed** (return -1) but **no crash**

**Case 2:**

> 1. Create socket: Successfully
> 2. Connection to Server: Failed or even No connection (comment out
>      connecting function)
> 3. Send data --> **Crash**

And then, i tried 3 different values of socket **WITHOUT** connection to server

**Case 3:**

> 1. ServerSocket = -1   --> Send data: Failed
> 2. ServerSocket =  0   --> Send data: Failed
> 3. ServerSocket =  4   --> Send data: **Crash**

In case of failed sending, it is correct but I don't understand why i got crash in other cases. I tried with Windows but no problem, is that a different between Linux and Windows? does it make sense? I want to open socket and connect to server only once time and after that sending data a thousand times, so if "the crash" makes sense in this case, how can I fix this problem in case of failed connection? Thanks for your time.

Here is the Case 2 (connect failed by stopping Server in order to test a case of failed connection):

```
ServerSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_IP) ;
...
iResult = connect(ServerSocket,(struct sockaddrx *)&server , sizeof(server));
iResult = send(ServerSocket, cSendBuff, strlen(cSendBuff), 0);
if(iResult<0)
{...}
```

Here is the Case 3:

```
    //ServerSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_IP) ;
    ...
    //iResult = connect(ServerSocket,(struct sockaddrx *)&server , sizeof(server));
    ServerSocket = 0;
    iResult = send(ServerSocket, cSendBuff, strlen(cSendBuff), 0);
    log();
    ServerSocket = -1;
    iResult = send(ServerSocket, cSendBuff, strlen(cSendBuff), 0);
    log();
    ServerSocket = 4;
    iResult = send(ServerSocket, cSendBuff, strlen(cSendBuff), 0);
    log();
    if(iResult<0)
    {...}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Don't post code in comments please. Edit it into your question. You can see for yourself that without formatting, which you can't do in comments, it is completely illegible. I don't see any error checking in this code, so it is impossible to tell what exactly you mean by 'fail' or 'crash'. Please clarify. And please post *all* the relevant code.

Comment: That is my Case 3, in the log, the programm crash after `ServerSocket = 4`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your program does **not** *crash*!

It receives a `SIGPIPE` signal because the local end of the socket has been shut down. Read [`man 2 send`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html), especially the `EPIPE` error case. (So, to be precise, your program is terminated due to an unhandled `SIGPIPE` signal.)

As the [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page says, the default disposition for `SIGPIPE` is to terminate the process. To avoid the termination, either set a `SIGPIPE` signal handler, or use `send(socket, buffer, length, MSG_NOSIGNAL)`.

Do not use Windows as your measuring stick. It is not a sane method. You have much better, actually reliable documentation available. The [Linux man-pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/) project is one of the best sources for the C library documentation ([section 3](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_3.html)). Even though it is focused on Linux and GNU C library, every page has a *Conforming to*  section which tells you when and where that functionality is available.

The above links refer to the up-to-date web pages, but you can also use `man 2 send`, `man 7 signal` on the command line to browse the same information. The web pages are more up to date than the distributions, but the project only includes standard man pages, not those installed by applications or extra libraries you might have.

Questions?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment. So maybe it is because of using 0 in `iResult = send(ServerSocket, cSendBuff, strlen(cSendBuff), 0);`. And I should change into `iResult = send(ServerSocket, cSendBuff, strlen(cSendBuff), MSG_NOSIGNAL);`. is it right?

Comment: @hoangsonvnu: If you do not want the `SIGPIPE` signal (which is causing your program to terminate -- what you thought was a "crash"), then use the `MSG_NOSIGNAL` flag. Come on, this is not that difficult. Read the linked references!

Answer (score 0):

Case 2.3: This should fail, by which I mean it should return -1 with an accompanying value of `errno.` You don't state what *you* mean by 'fail' or 'crash,' so it is impossible to comment further.

Case 3:
These should all fail ditto unless FD 0 or 4 happens to be a socket.

I have no idea why you're even testing any of this. A 'failed connection' is a completely different thing from a socket that has never been connected in the first place. A 'failed connection' manifests itself as a -1 return from `send(), recv(),` and friends, with an accompanying value of `errno` other than `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.` You can't send to a TCP socket that isn't connected, and it shouldn't be possible for your code to even attempt it. If it is, your error handling code path is incorrect.

Comment: **Fail** means `Return (-1)`, and it makes sense according to my understanding. I know we can't send data if no connection, but I have to take care of all cases in real system. After connecting, I send data by a thousand of `send()` command, and during its running, the connection might be lost any time by any reason. In this case, I got crash instead of keeping running

Comment: You got *what* 'crash?' What symptoms? And you certainly don't have to take care of the case of sending where the socket never got connected. Your code should make it impossible. This is all pointless. Your code just has to react correctly to the real live cases where `send()` or `recv()` return -1 etc as in my answer.

Comment: The program crash, it stops, no more running, no return anything. Of course I react after sending by `if(iResult==-1)` then ...But in case of crash, I even cannot get the value -1 after sending. As i said, the program stopped right after `send()`, it cannot run the next command, cannot return -1 to check. That 's the point. So i wonder why it is, it doesn't make sense as I know

Comment: No signal? No `SIGSEGV` for example? or `SIGPIPE?` No core dump? No calling `exit()` or `abort()` or `assert()` on your part? This is not plausible.